# How to change time format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to make a timeline using google visualization. I found  in documentation sample code and it seems like if I will only change  the row values it should be fine.

My data looks like this [TimeLineData](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Fyd93fW-BJxJ5OFUH3e-aogiVRnNW9ZrqVuu6JQ8yA/edit?usp=sharing)
So you can see that I have everything I need to do this.

My problem is how Can I change dates from column C and D

from this: [Thu Oct 29 09:05:00 GMT+09:00 2020]
to this:  new Date(2020,10,29,9,5,0),

It is needed to put into the row which should look like this:
(from the example)

```
[ 'Magnolia Room', 'Beginning JavaScript',       new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,13,30,0) ],
```

I guess you can use array from the whole range but I have no idea how can I process the whole array so I divided it into 4 parts. I don't know if its correct.

Data in spreadsheet are in the same order as it should be in the row

```
 [ 'Machine', 'Product',       new Date(start),  new Date(end) ],
```

Any advice will be helpful!

This is what I got:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function timelineData(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Array");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow(), srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  
  const machine = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const order = srcSheet.getRange(2, 2, srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  const startDate = srcSheet.getRange(2, 3, srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const endDate = srcSheet.getRange(2, 4, srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
        
  

}

  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Machine' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Order' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
       [ 'Magnolia Room', 'Beginning JavaScript',       new Date(0,0,0,12,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,13,30,0) ],
      [ 'Magnolia Room', 'Intermediate JavaScript',    new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,15,30,0) ],
      [ 'Magnolia Room', 'Advanced JavaScript',        new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0),  new Date(0,0,0,17,30,0) ],
      [ 'Willow Room',   'Beginning Google Charts',    new Date(0,0,0,12,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,14,0,0) ],
      [ 'Willow Room',   'Intermediate Google Charts', new Date(0,0,0,14,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,16,0,0) ],
      [ 'Willow Room',   'Advanced Google Charts',     new Date(0,0,0,16,30,0), new Date(0,0,0,18,0,0) ]

    ]);

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }
</script>

<div id="example3.1" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

So I edited code with the code from @Marios and now it looks like this:

```
     function drawChart() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("timeLineData");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange('A2:D'+srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const newAr = srcValues.map(r=>[r[0],r[1],new Date(r[2]),new Date(r[3])]);
    var container = document.getElementById('example5.1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Room' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows(newAr);

    var options = {
      timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
```

I don't know why but it is not working

Comment: @Marios I didnt notice that formatting is wrong, anyway its just sample data and the real data has a correct formatting. Expected output is  something that I can put into visualization code. I have tried something like this `dataTable.addRows([
machine,
  order,
  startDate,
  endDate
]);`
but id does not worked...

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  `document` is not defined anywhere in the code. You want to plot graphs in the google spreadsheet or in some sort of a web app ?

Comment: @Marios yes, I want to make it in web app so the above code is on the html side and on the script side I have only doGet function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

- I believe your goal is to create an array where the third and fourth column are date objects.
- You actually need to apply `new Date()` to every element in the third and fourth column of your data.
- You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to accomplish your goal:

  `const newAr = srcValues.map(r=>[r[0],r[1],new Date(r[2]),new Date(r[3])]);`

---

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("timeLineData");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange('A2:D'+srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const newAr = srcValues.map(r=>[r[0],r[1],new Date(r[2]),new Date(r[3])]);
  Logger.log(newAr)
}
```

and then you should be able to pass that array to `dataTable.addRows`:

`dataTable.addRows(newAr)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, this is what I am trying to achieve. but somehow it doesn't working.... I think I put code correctly but its not showing anything...  Do you know what may be wrong?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you just tried and what is not working? Do you see any errors?

Comment: @Pimo But I think the issue is that `newAr` is defined in `timelineData` but you want to use it in `drawChart` which is not accessible. Try to put all of your code into one function.

Comment: I edited question as you asked. I have no idea why its not working. The code you gave me is in the drawChart function